# Turning off deform for all bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

How do you turn off deform for all bones in a rig? I've tried selecting all the bones in Edit Mode and unchecking Deform, but going through each bone, I've noticed some are still checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all your bones in *Edit* mode, put your mouse cursor over the *Deform* checkbox, and click <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, it will deactivate the *Deform* option for all the selected bones.

Comment: Ahh. Perfect. Thank you. :D